# Can I have url_for use a prefix option in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a project I am working on, Apache is set up to only forward requests that come in as /prefix/* to mongrel. How can I tell ruby on rails to generate all URLs with that prefix?

I have the routes set up for forward to the correct controller action by doing this:

```
map.connect 'sfc/:controller/:action'
```

but that doesn't seem to affect the way that the url writer generates the URLs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongrel accepts a --prefix option that will then be prepended to all generated URLs. This is the only way I know of to be able to run multiple instances of the same application on one server.

Comment: Rails 2.3+ changes broke the --prefix option in mongrel and it has not been updated. You will have to monkey patch the code yourself to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

The `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` environment variable should do the trick, though I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have another route (probably one of the default routes at the bottom of routes.rb) that URL generation is using in preference to the sfc-prefixed match. For example, if you have

```
map.connect "sfc/:controller/:action"
map.connect ":controller/:action/:id"
```

then `url_for(:controller => 'x', :action => 'y', :id => 3)` will return `"/x/y/3"`. If you change it to

```
map.connect "sfc/:controller/:action"
map.connect "sfc/:controller/:action/:id"
```

you should get `"/sfc/x/y/3"`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the :path_prefix option:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action', :path_prefix => 'sfc'
```